# Iteration count in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, global-variables

I am writing a recursive function to make permutations of digits from `0` to `n`. The program will return the `th` permutation that is obtained. It all works well but I had to use the cheap trick of defining `count` as a list, that is `count=[0]`. In this way I am using the properties of lists in order to properly update the variable `count[0]` at each iteration.

Ideally, what I would like to do is to define `count` as an integer number instead. However, this does not work because `count` is then updated only locally, within the scope of the function at the time it is called.

What is the proper way to count the iterations in a recursive function like this?

Below I show the code. It works, but I hate the way I am using `count` here.

```
import numpy as np

N=10
available=np.ones(N)

def permutations(array, count=[0], n=N, start=0, end=N, th=100):
    if count[0]<th:
        for i in range(n):
            if available[i]:                           
                array[start]=i
                if end-start>1:
                    available[i]=0
                    permutations(array, count, n, start+1, end)
                    available[i]=1
                else:
                    count[0]+=1
                    break
            if count[0]==th:
                a=''.join(str(i) for i in array)
                return a

def main():
    array=[0 for _ in range(N)]
    count=[0]
    print(permutations(array, count, N, start=0, end=N))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You have tagged 'global-variables'. Did you try that?

Comment: Something very suspicious in your code: when you make the recursive call to `permutations(array, count, n, start+1, end)`, you completely ignore the return value.

Comment: In general I would recommend avoiding global variables at all costs for a function like this. There almost surely exists a better way. Note that your variable `available` is also a global variable. This can probably be avoided too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily ideal but to answer the question, one could use a global variable as follows:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
available = np.ones(N)
count = 0


def permutations(array, n=N, start=0, end=N, th=100):
    global count
    if count < th:
        for i in range(n):
            if available[i]:
                array[start] = i
                if end-start > 1:
                    available[i] = 0
                    permutations(array, n, start+1, end)
                    available[i] = 1
                else:
                    count += 1
                    break
            if count == th:
                return ''.join(str(i) for i in array)



def main():
    array = [0 for _ in range(N)]
    print(permutations(array, N, start=0, end=N))
    print(f'{count=}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
0123495786
count=100
```

Comment: Thank you, my mistake was to write `global count` outside the scope of the function, so I got the error `local variable 'count' referenced before assignment`.

Answer (score 1):

Different ways to update a variable from other *scopes*... and each with its own advantages and disadvantages (performance, access to the variable, ...):
with [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=nonlocal#the-global-statement) approach (as *Pingu* did),
with [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=nonlocal#the-nonlocal-statement)
and with function's attribute.

The example under consideration, the *factorial function*, is merely illustrative but it can be easily readapted to your case.

```
def fact_global(n):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n*fact_global(n-1)


def fact_nonlocal(n):
    counter = 0
    def __fact(n):
        nonlocal counter
        counter += 1
        
        if n == 1:
            return 1
        return n*__fact(n-1)
    return __fact(n)


def fact_attr(n):
    fact_attr.counter = 0
    def __fact(n):
        fact_attr.counter += 1
        
        if n == 1:
            return 1
        return n*__fact(n-1)
    return __fact(n)


n = 10
# case: global 
counter = 0
fact_global(n)
print('global', counter)

# case: nonlocal
fact_nonlocal(n)
import inspect
fr = inspect.currentframe()
print('nonlocal', fr.f_locals['counter']) # not recommended, just for curiosity!

# case: function's attribute
fact_attr(n)
print('attr', fact_attr.counter)
```

Retrieving the value of the variable under investigation is quite straightforward with a `global`-setting and with function's attribute but not trivial (and not recommended) with `nonlocal` ([`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) is more a debugging tool).

Here a partial result of the [workbench](https://www.onlinegdb.com/dM3NhLySC):

```
n=860
fact_nonlocal(n):   2.60644 ± 0.00586
fact_global(n):     2.74698 ± 0.02283
fact_attr(n):       3.01219 ± 0.00539
```

The results are of the same order of magnitude (due to limitations of the host only tested with a maximum of `n=860` so not reliable for an asymptotic conclusion), in **this** case it seems that it doesn't really matter which one you choose but it is more important to focus on how you are going to access to the variable later in the program.